# PHP content's style changes page to page?

Tags: php, css, styles

I am still learning but this has me a bit perplexed. I have pages that are populated using PHP pulling the content from my database. Each of these pages are styled the same way. However, when I was testing them all, some of them vary and I'm not sure why.

This is the PHP:

```
<div id="container">
     <?php

        $result = mysql_query ("SELECT id, large_images, project_name, category_name, description, applications_used, web
                            FROM projects 
                            WHERE {$_GET['id']}=id") or die ("mysql_query error");

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 

            {

            $large_image = $row['large_images'];
            $large_image = explode(",", $large_image);

            $applications_used = $row ['applications_used'];
            $applications_used = explode(",", $applications_used);

            echo "<div id='info'>";
                echo "<div class='banner2'><p>{$row['project_name']}</p></div>";
                echo "<div class='category'><h3>{$row['category_name']}</h3></div>";
                echo "<div id='description'>{$row['description']}";
                    echo "<div class='web_link'><p>{$row['web']}</p></div>";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "<div id='applications'><h4>Applications</h4>{$row['applications_used']}</div>";
            echo "</div>";

            echo "<div id='slideshow_container'>";
                echo "<div id='slides'>";
                    echo "<div class='slides_container'>";

                            foreach($large_image as $large_image)
                                {
                                    echo "<div><img src='images/portfolio/large/$large_image' alt='{$row[project_name]}' width='100%' /></div>";    
                                }
                    echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "<div id='extra'>";
                echo "<span></span>";
            echo "</div>";

            }
?>


        </div>
```

I styled it to make the page look like this one:

http://www.liannesuggitt.com/test/portfolio/slideshow.php?%20id=0

However, sometimes it looks like this (too high):

http://www.liannesuggitt.com/test/portfolio/slideshow.php?%20id=1

or this for too low: (I don't have enough rep, replace the last bit with id=9)

The CSS is in two places, one titled portfolio_slideshow.css and is as follows: (adapted from slidesjs.com)

```
#slideshow_container
{
height: 500px;
width: 702px;
margin: -775px auto 0 auto;
}
#slideshow_container:after
{
    display:block;
    clear: both;
    content: "";
}

/*
Slides container
Important:
Set the width of your slides container
Set to display none, prevents content flash
*/

.slides_container {
    width: 702px;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    height: 552px;
    margin: -770px auto 0 auto;
    float: left;
}

    .slides_container img
    {
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 700px;
        height: 550px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

/*
Each slide
Important:
Set the width of your slides
If height not specified height will be set by the slide content
Set to display block
*/

.slides_container a {
    width:90%;
    height:400px;
    display:block;
}





/*
Pagination
*/

.pagination {
    margin: 720px auto auto 35%;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}


.pagination li {
    float:left;
    margin:0 1px;
    list-style:none;
}

.pagination li:first-child
{
    margin-left: 10px;  
}

.pagination li a {
    display:block;
    width:13px;
    height:0;
    padding-top:14px;
    background-image:url(../img/pagination.png);
    background-position:0 0;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.pagination li a:hover
{
background-position:0 -25px;
}

.pagination li.current a {
background-position:0 -13px;
}
```

And the other is from style.css, here is the snippet involved in that:

```
    #info
{
    width: 78%;
    margin: 590px auto 0 auto;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 15px;
}

    #description p
    {
        text-align: justify;    
    }

.banner2
{
    background: url("../images/banner.png");
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 200;
    margin-top: -580px;
    margin-left: -110px;
    color: white;

}

    .banner2 p
    {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 110%;
        line-height: 30px;
        font-family: 'Conv_Essays1743';
    }

.category
{
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-family: 'Conv_Essays1743';
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
    .category h3
    {
        font-family: 'Conv_Essays1743';
        color: black;
        font-size: 120%;    
        margin-left: -25px;
        margin-bottom: 15px; 
    }


#description
{
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    float: left;
    width: 82%;
}



    #description p
    {
        margin-bottom: 5px; 
    }

#applications
{
    /*border: 1px solid green;*/    
    height: 29%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    float: right;
    width: 12%;
}

    #applications h4
    {
        font-family: 'Conv_Essays1743';
        margin-bottom: 8px; 
    }

.web_link
{
    margin-top: -7px;   
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
}

    .web_link a
    {
        color: black;
        text-transform: uppercase;  
        font-family: 'Conv_Essays1743';
        font-size: 80%;

    }

        .web_link a:hover
        {   
            color: #5a5a5a;
        }
```

Sorry if this is lengthy, I figured it would be easier to see the code versus hunting for it!
And I'm aware there is some weird margins on the slideshow portion, there were a lot of strange div's (to my knowledge haha)

Thanks for any information,

Comment: advice : dont use mysql_* functions , they are not maintained anymore , use either pdo or mysqli , check the php docs.

Comment: It seems to be a css problem actually. I'd play around with the heights and margins of the container/images.

Comment: Thanks @clamidity, that is what I have been trying to do, I was just wondering if the issue jumped off the page for anyone.

Comment: Ok, I will look more into the php docs, thanks @mpm

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so to solve the dilemma I had to rearrange the php so that the "slideshow" portion was first instead of the content, and style accordingly. Before, the placement of the slideshow depended on where the content ended (because the margin-top of the slideshow was being calculated from the end point of the content's div), and since the content's length was varying on each page, it caused the slideshow to shift it's placement.

It was still x amount of pixels up, it's just that the point it was calculating it from was shifting.

Thanks to those who took a look.